# Express.js: Specifying a root route breaks static file resolvement

Tags: javascript, express, express-router

I'm trying to make an express.js / react.js app but I'm running into a couple of issues I find no answer for.

I set up a base directory that holds the express server, and a subdirectory called client which holds my react application.

When I use the default, as used in many examples:

```js
app.get( express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'client/build' ) ) );
```

The app works and loads every file correctly.

But I would prefer to not have the app run at the root of my server but instead in a subdirectory. e.g. `/app`.

So, according to what I've found. All I need to change in my `server.js` is the following:

```js
app.get( '/app', express.static( /*...*/ ) );
```

I also modified my react app to change its links to include `/app`. However, adding a root breaks everything. While the default `index.html` does load. None of the other files get loaded.
When trying to request the link to one of the files. I get `Cannot GET /app/favicon.ico` (per example), The same message I get when requesting a non existing path.

Without any success I have also tried:

```js
router.get( express.static( /*...*/ ) );
app.get( '/app', router );
```

and

```js
app.route( '/app' ).get( express.static( /*...*/ ) );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems I'm mixing up express.get and express.use. I'm now using `router.use( express.static );` and `server.use( path, router );` and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out. You would have to use `express.use` instead of `express.get`. At first I didn't understand the difference but after changing all calls to `.use`. everything worked.

Working code:

```
app.use( '/app', express.static( /*...*/ ) );
```

as well as

```
const approuter = express.Router();
approuter.use( express.static( /*...*/ ) );
app.use( '/app', approuter );
```